# What is orange fine dust after vacuuming a new carpet in an old house

Tags: mold, old-house, carpet, dust, dry-rot

I installed a new carpet in an old house. Vacuuming the new carpet picked up orange fine dust. Do you know what might cause the dust? Do I need to worry about it?

Is it possible a hidden dry-rot issue or some types of mould?

[image]

Comment: If there was a carpet there before, likely it's the deteriorated rubber backing that had been removed. But the dust could be **anything**. For example, the past year has seen heavy forest fires in North America, and it could be dust from that.

Comment: It made me think of old carpet padding or backing.

Comment: The only definitive test for mould or dry rot is a test.  But it is unlikely that it is either.

Comment: New carpet *and* new padding?

Comment: Yes, new carpet and padding. I wasn't there when the installer laid down the carpet so I had no idea if that was dirty subfloors. Hence, it's very hard to tell what the problem is at the moment.